# Elasticsearch query for sum of part of a document

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, sum, range

I have documents in the following style in my index:

```
{
  "docType": {
    "valuesOverTime": [
        {
            "begin": 1488442858570,
            "end": 1488442860570,
            "values": [
                {
                    "name": "level",
                    "segCount": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "begin": 1488442860571,
            "end": 1488442890592,
            "mcdn": [
                {
                    "name": "level",
                    "segCount": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "begin": 1488442890593,
            "end": 1488442890600,
            "mcdn": [
                {
                    "name": "level",
                    "segCount": 7
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

and want to query the sum of the docType.valuesOverTime.values.segCount in a certain time range, like the following range

```
{
  "range": {
    "docType.valuesOverTime.begin": {
      "gte": 1488442858570,
      "lte": 1488442860571
    }
  }
},
{
  "range": {
    "docType.valuesOverTime.end": {
      "gte": 1488442860570,
      "lte": 1488442890592

    }
  }
}
```

should get me the sum of the first two entries: 14.

However I am absolutely stuck getting the query right! I always get the sum of all the entries in docType.valueOverTime.values.segCount being 21 in this case.

I tried the following queries and some variations on them which where of course all wrong:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "myfilter": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "docType.valuesOverTime.begin": {
                      "gte": 1488442858570,
                      "lte": 1488442860571
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "docType.valuesOverTime.end": {
                      "gte": 1488442860570,
                      "lte": 1488442890592

                    }
                  }
                }                   
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "summe": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "docType.valuesOverTime.values.segCount"
              }
            }
          }
        } 
    }
}
```

and

```
{
  "_source": "docType.valuesOverTime.values", 
  "query": {
    "constant_score" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "docType.valuesOverTime.begin": {
                  "gte": 1488442858570,
                  "lte": 1488442860571
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "docType.valuesOverTime.end": {
                  "gte": 1488442860570,
                  "lte": 1488442890592

                }
              }
            }   

          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "summe": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "docType.valuesOverTime.values.segCount"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please tell me, what I got wrong? And how to do it right!

Working on es 5.2.2 with the following mapping

```
"valuesOverTime": {
    "properties": {
      "begin": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "end": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "values": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "segCount": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself:

first, everything in valuesOverTime needs to be nested, so that the mapping looks like

```
"valuesOverTime": {
    "type": nested"
    "properties": {
      "begin": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "end": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "values": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "segCount": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then I can query as follows:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "nestedAcq": {
      "nested": {"path": "docType.valuesOverTime"},
      "aggs": {
        "rangeAcq": {
          "range": {
            "field": "ocType.valuesOverTime.begin",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": 1488442858570,
                "to": 1488442860572
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "theSum": {
              "sum": {                
                "field": "docType.valuesOverTime.values.segCount"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } 

    }
  }
}
```

and get

```
"theSum": {
    "value": 14
}
```